# How to recover Wildfly HEURISTIC_HAZARD transaction?

Tags: wildfly, jboss7.x, activemq-artemis

I'm using Wildfly 14.0.1.Final. Transaction has two resource managers:

- Oracle Database
- External ActiveMQ Artemis message broker

I can see that WFs recovery subsystem is trying to recover this transaction every 3 mins:

```
 [Periodic Recovery] WARN com.arjuna.ats.arjuna restore_state():1161  - Transaction 0:ffffa9fecb0f:7ee603d5:5f3d19b3:310a130 has 1 heuristic participant(s)!
 [Periodic Recovery] WARN com.arjuna.ats.jta  null():-1 - ARJUNA016037: Could not find new XAResource to use for recovering non-serializable XAResource XAResourceRecord < resource:null, txid:< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffffa9fecb0f:7ee603d5:5f3d19b3:310a130, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffffa9fecb0f:7ee603d5:5f3d19b3:310a13f, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:/jms/remoteCFArtemis NodeId:dc5d6b03-cb07-11e9-819c-02004c4f4f50 >, heuristic: TwoPhaseOutcome.HEURISTIC_HAZARD, product: ActiveMQ Artemis/2.6.3.jbossorg-001, jndiName: java:/jms/remoteCFArtemis NodeId:dc5d6b03-cb07-11e9-819c-02004c4f4f50 com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord@5d8b9a5d >
 [Periodic Recovery] WARN com.arjuna.ats.jta restore_state():1060 - XAResourceRecord restored heuristic instance: XAResourceRecord < resource:null, txid:< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffffa9fecb0f:7ee603d5:5f3d19b3:310a130, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffffa9fecb0f:7ee603d5:5f3d19b3:310a13f, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:/jms/remoteCFArtemis NodeId:dc5d6b03-cb07-11e9-819c-02004c4f4f50 >, heuristic: TwoPhaseOutcome.HEURISTIC_HAZARD, product: ActiveMQ Artemis/2.6.3.jbossorg-001, jndiName: java:/jms/remoteCFArtemis NodeId:dc5d6b03-cb07-11e9-819c-02004c4f4f50 com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord@5d8b9a5d >
 [Periodic Recovery] WARN com.arjuna.ats.arjuna restore_state():1186  - Transaction 0:ffffa9fecb0f:7ee603d5:5f3d19b3:310a130 restored heuristic participant XAResourceRecord < resource:null, txid:< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffffa9fecb0f:7ee603d5:5f3d19b3:310a130, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffffa9fecb0f:7ee603d5:5f3d19b3:310a13f, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:/jms/remoteCFArtemis NodeId:dc5d6b03-cb07-11e9-819c-02004c4f4f50 >, heuristic: TwoPhaseOutcome.HEURISTIC_HAZARD, product: ActiveMQ Artemis/2.6.3.jbossorg-001, jndiName: java:/jms/remoteCFArtemis NodeId:dc5d6b03-cb07-11e9-819c-02004c4f4f50 com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord@5d8b9a5d >
```

From the log, I can see it is an **HEURISTIC_HAZARD**.
jboss-cli is giving me following when I query transaction data:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=transactions/log-store=log-store/transactions=0\:ffffa9fecb0f\:7ee603d5\:5f3d19b3\:310a130:read-resource(include-runtime=true)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "age-in-seconds" => "8",
        "id" => "0:ffffa9fecb0f:7ee603d5:5f3d19b3:310a130",
        "jmx-name" => undefined,
        "type" => "StateManager/BasicAction/TwoPhaseCoordinator/AtomicAction",
        "participants" => {"1" => undefined}
    }
}
```

And when I query the only participant I get the following:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=transactions/log-store=log-store/transactions=0\:ffffa9fecb0f\:7ee603d5\:5f3d19b3\:310a130/participants=1:read-resource(include-runtime=true)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "eis-product-name" => undefined,
        "eis-product-version" => undefined,
        "jmx-name" => undefined,
        "jndi-name" => "1",
        "status" => "HEURISTIC",
        "type" => "/StateManager/AbstractRecord/XAResourceRecord"
    }
}
```

Pretty much everything is undefined, but I see this participant is Artemis resource manager from the log.

Does anyone have a clue on how to resolve this transaction?

Comment: Hi Mike, did you solve this problem. If so then let me know  the solution.

Comment: Hi Narayan. No, I didn't solve the issue...